# SQL: Querying between two tables

Tags: sql

I have a table called `mapunit` in which there is a column called `muname` and the primary key is called `mukey`.

I have another table called `SpatialJoin`, which also has the primary key as `mukey`. For each row in `SpatialJoin`, I want to retrieve the corresponding `muname`.

I tried:

```
SELECT muname 
FROM mapunit 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT mukey FROM SpatialJoin)
```

but that didn't work. Any suggestions for how I could rewrite my statement would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're picking all rows from from *mapunit* where the key *exists in SpatialJoin*, not quite what you want.

Try selecting every row from *SpatialJoin* instead and just join with *mapunit* to get the name;

```
SELECT muname
FROM SpatialJoin sj
JOIN mapunit mu ON mu.mukey = sj.mukey
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    mu.MuName, mu.mukey
FROM
    SpatialJoin sj
INNER JOIN
    Mapunit mu ON sj.mukey = mu.mukey
```

The `INNER JOIN` will "join" the two tables on the defined JOIN condition, and now you can select columns from both tables in your `SELECT`. The `INNER JOIN` also joins only rows from both tables that have that common column (and the same value in that common column).

**Update:** to get `CompName` from a third `Component` table, try this:

```
SELECT
    mu.MuName, mu.mukey, c.CompName
FROM
    SpatialJoin sj
INNER JOIN
    Mapunit mu ON sj.mukey = mu.mukey
INNER JOIN
    Component c ON sj.mukey = c.mukey
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But now I am trying to retrieve a column called compname from another table called Component. The Component table has mukey as a relative key and there is a one to many relationship. How do I need to change the code in order to retrieve the compname(s) for each row in SpatialJoin?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.muname
FROM mapunit m, SpatialJoin s
WHERE m.mukey=s.mukey
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the proper **ANSI standard JOIN syntax** (`INNER JOIN ....` etc.) instead of just listing table after table in a comma-separated way. The ANSI syntax is cleaner and tends to produce less unwanted cartesian products by missing a JOIN condition, and it keeps the `WHERE` clause cleaner (since the JOIN conditions are where they belong - on the JOIN statement itself)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT b.muname
FROM SpatialJoin a INNER JOIN mapunit b
        on a.mukey = b.mukey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT muname
FROM SpatialJoin s
JOIN mapunit m ON m.mukey = s.mukey
```

try this may work

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: i was using StackOverFlow Mobile Site

Comment: Then indent your lines of code by four spaces to get the same result